# Изменения в UserDefaults применяются только после перезапуска приложения

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, uiviewcontroller

У меня есть 3 вьюхи.

Сначала показывается первая в течение 5 секунд, там можно нажать на кнопку перехода к настройкам и тогда показывается вторая вьюха с настройками, где можно изменить данные в UserDefaults, после сохранения изменений, открывается другая вьюха, в которой применяются эти настройки, но сейчас применяются старые настройки, а новые применяются только после перезапуска приложения

Я не понимаю в чём дело, тк вроде с UserDefaults ничего не напутал.

По ощущениям, словно параметры третьей вьюшки инициализируются до того, как сделаются изменения в настройках, поэтому они и не применяются.

Пожалуйста, подскажите в чём дело.

StartViewController.swift (1-ая вьюха):

```
class StartViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer : Timer!

    @IBAction func goSettings(_ sender: Any) {
        timer.invalidate()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SettingsView", sender: self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(toMainView), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.onDidBecomeActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
    }
    func onDidBecomeActive() {
        setOrientationLandscape()
    }

    // Change orientation to landscape
    private func setOrientationLandscape() {
        if !UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
            UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey:"orientation")
            UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
        }
    }

    // Only allow landscape left
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func toMainView(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainView", sender: self)
    }

}
```

SettingsViewController.swift (2-ая вьюха):

```
struct SettingsKeys{
    static let Portal = "myportal"
    static var DefPortal = "myportal.ru"
}

extension UserDefaults {
    func setDefPortal(value: String) {
        set(value, forKey: SettingsKeys.Portal)
    }
    func getDefPortal() -> String {
        return string(forKey: SettingsKeys.Portal) ?? SettingsKeys.DefPortal
    }
}

class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var portalUrl: UITextField!

    @IBAction func saveSettings(_ sender: Any) {
        UserDefaults.standard.setDefPortal(value: portalUrl.text ?? SettingsKeys.DefPortal)
        portalUrl.endEditing(true)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainView", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func restoreDefaultPortal(_ sender: Any) {
        portalUrl.text = SettingsKeys.DefPortal
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.onDidBecomeActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
        portalUrl.delegate = self;
    }

    func onDidBecomeActive() {
        setOrientationLandscape()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        portalUrl.endEditing(true);
        return true
    }

    // Change orientation to landscape
    private func setOrientationLandscape() {
        if !UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
            UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey:"orientation")
            UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
        }
    }

    // Only allow landscape left
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        portalUrl.text = UserDefaults.standard.getDefPortal()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

ViewController.swift (3-я вьюха):

```
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("hello hell")
        var res = UserDefaults.standard.getDefPortal()
        res = "http://" + res + "/?screen=1280x720
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.onDidBecomeActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
    }
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переместите применение параметров из viewDidLoad в viewWillAppear.

Добавлю: viewDidLoad вызывается при создании экрана (как правило, 1 раз), а viewWillAppear каждый раз, перед тем, как экран отображается (например, после перехода на другой экран и возврата).

Comment: Знаете, как-то по грани ответа и комментария.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/330034)

Comment: @AK Согласен. Но вопрос то такой, что это и есть ответ. Как его расширить, я прямо и не знаю.

Comment: @freim Это не замечание и не уточнение. Это исправление, которое должно решить проблему. Да, примитивное.

Comment: Не в первый раз замечаю, что если оставить комментарий "на грани ответа" и пропустить проверку - то потом найдутся желающие грохнуть "не является ответом". Эй, люди - я "мимокрокодил", я не жал "удалить". ))

Comment: @A K, не надо преувеличивать свою роль, ваш комментарий совершенно не повлиял. До дополнения этот ответ на полноценный ответ никак не тянул. С дополнением это уже гораздо ближе к ответу, сейчас я бы нажал "выглядит нормально".

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь в моём вопросе, мне это помогло
P.S.: Не ругайтесь, я теперь буду часто вопросы сюда выкладывать по swift, на всех хватит ;)